# How to create a uiview with round corners having center hole?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to create a uiview with round corners having center hole that means only a circle with center blank?

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: yes..i create two uiview with round corners having two different radius.and add overlap that

Comment: please post a screenshot of what would you like to achieve and any relevant code you have done to achieve it

Comment: want a circle rather a large dot?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a bezier path with oval rect.

```
UIBezierPath* ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: CGRectMake(67, 18, 50, 50)];
[UIColor.grayColor setStroke];
ovalPath.lineWidth = 1.5;
[ovalPath stroke];
```

You can increas the line width to make the center hole smaller.

For line width 25:

[image]

For line width 1.5:

[image]

If you want to have the hole in a rectnagular view:

```
- (void)drawFrame: (CGRect)frame
{

    UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 13, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 13, 50, 50) cornerRadius: 8];
    [UIColor.darkGrayColor setStroke];
    rectanglePath.lineWidth = 8;
    [rectanglePath stroke];

    UIBezierPath* ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 25, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 25, 26, 26)];
    [UIColor.darkGrayColor setStroke];
    ovalPath.lineWidth = 31;
    [ovalPath stroke];
}
```

[image]

Comment: The question was about creating a special shaped UIView. This solution provides the required shape but you cannot display arbitrary content on that shape. Creating a UIBezierPath is good first step, but the comprehensive solution includes the UIView masking with that path. Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I'm not sure what do you want.
Since, you mentioned UIView, so this maybe help.

```
UIView* v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
v.layer.cornerRadius = 5;// this property will round the square corner
UIView* v2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(v.center.x- 50, v.center.y- 50, 100, 100)];
v2.layer.cornerRadius = 50;// if you set the value by half the frame size, it will be like circle.
v2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[v addSubview:v2];
```

Comment: What if you want to see the content of `v.superview` in the hole?

Answer (score 0):

You can mask your UIView to achieve arbitrary shape. I give an examlpe how to produce a circle with a hole inside.

```
UIView * redRing = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
redRing.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(100, 100);
CGFloat R = 100; //circle radius
CGFloat r = 50; //hole radius
UIBezierPath* maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center radius:R startAngle:0 endAngle:2*M_PI clockwise:YES];
[maskPath appendPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center radius:r startAngle:0 endAngle:2*M_PI clockwise:NO]];
CAShapeLayer* mask = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
[mask setPath:maskPath.CGPath];
redRing.layer.mask = mask;
```

Answer (score -1):

use UIImageView instead of UIView, set proper image with centre transperent to To that ImageView , the image you design as per  your requirement and set background color clearclor for UIImageview

Comment: y , it is absolutely wrong please explain

Comment: he can use image with centre hole and having border.

Answer (score -1):

Please Explain more in Detail about it or post any reference image for it because it is not possible using UIView.

For your solution you can make one image(UIImageView) like that.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: Than Give a solution for that and please make sure that it is posible using UIView. @Desdenova

Comment: Without the use case it's pretty much impossible to answer this question.

Comment: You are right but my answer is proper for the question what she asked for it.@Desdenova

Comment: Your "answer" would have been more appropriate as a comment....